# Asynchronous message on a synchronous connetion. JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, serversocket

I wonder if anyone could help me with ideas on how to go on my project. 
Basically what I have is a networking program using Serversocket to allow connections from clients, for each new connection I start a new Thread. They work great but they only can send one message at a time to the server and only when the server sends a response back the client is allowed to type a new message. What I wanted to do is to create a "notification message" that would be Asynchronous. 
Basically the client request something and the server will send it back whenever it meets the client query, but it has to be done while the server and client still communicating.

"The request from the client would be: be informed when something changes on the server side such as bookings availiability.

What I tried so far was NotificationBus using JGroups
JMS which i coudnt do.
I wa trying to create a new thread to do that but i am not luck with that either, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Netty4? It supports completely asynchronous two way comms.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look.